# ¿Como se usa Request como parametro en función?

Tags: php

¿Que significa `Request` en este código?

```
public static function run(Request $peticion){}
```

¿Request es una palabra reservada que cumpla alguna función?¿Dónde puedo encontrar información sobre ella?

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework o algo? si es así, revisa la doc de dicho framework. Se podría decir que `Request` es una clase, y que `$peticion` es un objeto del tipo de esa clase (una *instancia*  de la clase `Request`). Puedes por ejemplo hacer `var_dump($peticion);` para obtener información sobre ese objeto.

Comment: En ese codigo en concreto `Request` es un tipo de objeto, de manera que cuando se llame a esa función debes mandar un objeto de ese tipo como parametro. La información de ese objeto dependeria de la libreria o el framework que tienes

Comment: Por ejemplo, si precisaras usar el método `run` que muestras, tendrías que: 1º. Crear una instancia u objeto del tipo `Request`. Algo así, o parecido: `$mRequest=new Request(<parametros si fuera preciso>);`  2º. Llamas a `run` pasándole esa instancia: `LaClaseDeRun::run($mRequest);`

Comment: Si veo que Request es una clase "class Request" que hay en un require a request.php. Me resulta extraño por que para crear una instancia yo hago $peticion= new Request(); Pero en este ejemplo se crea desde otro archivo asi: Bootstrap::run(new Request); y con esto accede a otro archivo donde hay esto: public static function run(Request $peticion){} . Me desconcierta un poco el funcionamiento. ¿Podría explicarlo un poco para alguien que lo ve por primera vez? Gracias

Comment: Vale, no se si lo entendí bien. ¿Seria equivalente a poner): $peticion= new Request();
  Bootstrap::run($peticion); y en el otro archivo: public static function run($peticion) ???

Comment: No entiendo bien cuál es tu duda. Si usas esto así: `Bootstrap::run($peticion);` significa que `run` debe estar en la clase llamada `Bootstrap`, no *en otro archivo*. Lo que haces ahí es llamar a ese método (`run`)  de tu clase. Y los dos puntos que usas en la llamada `::` es porque el método es `static`.  Si hay alguna duda expresa con claridad cuál es la duda.

Comment: Si, la funcion "run" esta en la clase Bootstrap: public static function run(Request $peticion) {} (y entiendo el acceso a static mediante ::). Mi duda, que vosotros me ayudasteis a entender,  es por la parte que va en parametros: Request $peticion. Request es una clase y se pueden crear instancias a partir de ella, pero claro, a mi me resultaba extraño el hecho de que se realizara desde otro archivo con:  Bootstrap::run(new Request); sin crear el objeto como se hace tipicamente: $peticion=new Request; . Ya he visto que esta manera es diferente de hacerlo pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: La duda (si quieres confirmarme lo que creo es) es si esto:   Bootstrap::run(new Request); y en otro archivo dentro de clase Bootstrap: public static function run(Request $peticion){}. Sería lo mismo que esto:  $peticion= new Request(); Bootstrap::run($peticion); y en otro archivo dentro de clase Bootstrap: public static function run($peticion) ¿¿estas dos maneras de hacer son equivalentes la una a la otra?

Comment: Aun que no queda muy claro el ultimo comentario te dire que si, es igual: `$peticion= new Request(); Bootstrap::run($peticion);` y `Bootstrap::run(new Request);` son lo mismo. ¿Aun no entiendo cual es la duda concreta que tiene?

Comment: La duda es la forma de crear la instacia de peticion asi:public static function run(Request $peticion){}. No estoy familiarizado con esta manera de hacerlo. Pero y me quedó claro. Gracias!